# Include same jsp page in all jQuery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, jquery-ui

I want to include same JSP page in all jQuery tabs with unique tab ids, i.e. same *Comment.jsp* file in all jQuery tabs of *CommentTab.html*.
When I run the following code I am able to create new tabs but JSP page contents are not shown in any tab.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    var tabTitle = $( "#tab_title" ),
        tabContent = $( "#tab_content" ),
        tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
        tabCounter = 2;

    var tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

    // modal dialog init: custom buttons and a "close" callback reseting the form inside
    var dialog = $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Add: function() {
                addTab();
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            form[ 0 ].reset();
        }
    });

    // addTab form: calls addTab function on submit and closes the dialog
    var form = dialog.find( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
        addTab();
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    // actual addTab function: adds new tab using the input from the form above
    function addTab() {
        var label = tabTitle.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter,
            id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
            li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, "#" + id ).replace( /#\{label\}/g, label ) ),
            //tabContentHtml = tabContent.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter + " content.";
                tabContentHtml = getComments();

        tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
        tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>" );
        tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
        tabCounter++;
    }

function getComments(){
        $( "#success" ).load( "Comment.jsp", function( response, status, xhr ) {
              if ( status == "error" ) {
                var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
              }
            });
    }

    // addTab button: just opens the dialog
    $( "#add_tab" )
        .button()
        .click(function() {
            dialog.dialog( "open" );
        });

    // close icon: removing the tab on click
    $( "#tabs span.ui-icon-close" ).live( "click", function() {
        var panelId = $( this ).closest( "li" ).remove().attr( "aria-controls" );
        $( "#" + panelId ).remove();
        tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
    });
});
    </script>

<body>
<div id="dialog" title="Tab data">
    <form>
        <fieldset class="ui-helper-reset">
            <label for="tab_title">Title</label> <input type="text"
                name="tab_title" id="tab_title" value=""
                class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
  <div id="tab_content" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div>          
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

<button id="add_tab">Add Tab</button>


<div id="tabs">
    <ul>    
        <div id="success"></div>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Because you are creating links to the Comment.jsp page, not loading its content. See [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek That worked for me. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek It is not showing for every tab that I create. If you can just help me out. I have edited the code with _jQuery.load()_ function.

Comment: The problem is probably that you are loading the Comment.jsp's content always to the same div (`#success`) - jQuery.load() **replaces** the contant of the tab. You have to create a new div, with an unique ID, and pass it to the getComments() function to load the comments into the new div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved using iframe. The modified part of the code is as follows:
The script part:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var tabTitle = $( "#tab_title" ),
    tabContent = $( "#tab_content" ),
    tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
    tabCounter = 2;
    var websiteframe = '<iframe src="Comment.jsp" width="100%" height="100%" allowtransparency="true" frameBorder="0">Your browser does not support IFRAME</iframe>';

    var tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
```

Then include *websiteframe* in *addTab()* function:

```
    function addTab() {
        var label = tabTitle.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter,
            id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
            li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, "#" + id ).replace( /#\{label\}/g, label ) ),
            websiteframe = '<iframe src="Comment.jsp" width="100%" height="100%" allowtransparency="true" frameBorder="0">Your browser does not support IFRAME</iframe>';
        tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
        tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'>" + websiteframe + "</div>" );
        tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
        tabCounter++;
    }
```

The html part:

```
<button id="add_tab">Add Tab</button>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>

    </ul>   
</div>
```